# Is it possible to programmatically create a hash rule?

Tags: c#, powershell, hash, wmi

I wanted to programmatically create a Hash Rule under the Software Restriction Policies for Windows using either C#/VB, Powershell, WMI or anything that might work. Has anyone ever tried this before?

Comment: Hi, were you able to achieve this? I am also looking to create a Path Rule in C#.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure. This one was posted quite a long time ago for a campus job I had. I haven't been doing windows administration for over 4 years. If you find a solution, I'll be happy to mark it as an answer if you reply to this.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be a specific answer, but you can manage GPOs with PowerShell.  I found a link to an article from TechNet Magazine, [Simplify Group Policy Administration with Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.05.grouppolicy.aspx) ([Here is the download link to the code](http://download.microsoft.com/download/f/d/0/fd05def7-68a1-4f71-8546-25c359cc0842/GroupPolicy2007_05.exe)).

If you have a Server 2008 R2 box, there is a GPO module feature for PowerShell that you can turn on.

I also found this [set of GPO cmdlets](http://www.gpoguy.com/FreeTools/FreeToolsLibrary/tabid/67/agentType/View/PropertyID/91/Default.aspx) from GPOGUY.com.

Comment: the powershell GPO cmdlets allow you to create GPOs and modify permissions, but it doesn't look like there is anything to create a hash rule. Editing registry values are possible, but again it doesn't help much with creating a hash rule 8/